# Add repeat-item animation not working properly

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat, css-animations

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XdGHKhf5z5BQMaYk1Naz?p=preview), the animation of adding of an item is only working if first an item is deleted from the list. How to fix this?

css:

```
.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
}

.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
  height: 0px;
}
.repeat-item.ng-leave,
.repeat-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
   height: 30px;
}
.repeat-item {

  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

html:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items " class="repeat-item">
    {{item}} <span class="delete" ng-click="remove($index)">delete</span>
  </div>
  <div ng-click="add($index)">add</div>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Firefox or Safari, I can see an add-animation without deleting an item. Which  browser+version are you using? By the way, the AngularJS version you're using is outdated, 1.4 is latest. A lot of animation bugs have been fixed since 1.2.

Comment: Oh, indeed, I switched to 1.4.1 and then it worked perfectly. I am using Chrome. Thanks! Make an answer out of it and I will accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Comment from Blaise was really the answer. I had problems using Chrome. Solution was to switch from 1.2 to 1.4 of Angular/AngularAnimate, then it worked perfectly.